# How to invert a heatmap in 3D Maps?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using MS Excel's 3D maps tool to plot a bunch of coordinates to a real-life map and forming a heatmap. The map tells the density of some variable in different points accross the city, using X and Y coordinates.

My boss has asked me to "invert" the heatmap (meaning, it should show the points with the **LOWEST** density of this variable.

[image: Density heatmap]

Is there any easy way to do this? All I can think about is plotting a grid and checking every point for the existence of the variable, but that seems unintuitive. Isn't it?